# Need to reverse an integer array based on the input median

Tags: java, arrays

Need to reverse an array of integers based on the input number 
For example :

`Array be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and value of subset be N = 4

then the array after reversal will be [4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9].

if N = 3 then output should be [3,2,1,6,5,4,9,8,7]`

Couldn't think of a proper logic with recursive method or with any looping concepts

Comment: How would you reverse full array (when N = array length)?

Comment: Is N an index or a value in the array?

Comment: @klutt I think he needs to reverse all subarray of size exactly `4`

Comment: what is the 'input median'?

Comment: This is just an array reverse problem from start until N...unless the problem definition is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, but it does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below java code

```
public static int[] reverse(int[] a, int number) {
    // negative case
    if (number < 0) {
        return a;
    }
    // higher count than array length
    int size = number < a.length ? number : a.length;
    int[] b = new int[size];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, size);
    for (int i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        a[b.length - 1 - i] = b[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Array has index with each element so above loop code is simple and efficient.

Comment: Thank you So much. This was I looking for .

Comment: thanks, you can vote for my answer